# Running Save Participants runs forever on File Save

Tags: visual-studio-code

Unfortunately I am not sure how to debug or even begin to debug this error. If someone can help me out it would be a huge help. I wish I could provide more info but essentially when I try to save a file, this comes up and it does not go away and runs forever. It prevents me from saving any file.

[image]

Things I have tried.
1. Restarting VS Code
2. Rebooting computer
3. Disabling all VS Code Extensions.
4. Updating VS Code and running as Administrator.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Strangely, restarting VS Code *did* help in my case.

Answer (score 26):

In my VS Code, it's an issue that comes from an installed Extension.

How to find an extension did not work?

Open the Command Palette (**macOS**: <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or **Windows**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>), then type `Show Running Extensions` and enter.

[image]

If you have any `Inactivation` extension showed up here, reinstall or uninstall it will solve VSCode's slow issue.

[image]

Comment: another way to spot a problematic plugin is to check the messages in the lower bar as shown in @Pepeng Hapon's answer

Comment: Great answer. Helped me find an extension which blocked the entire process.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this'll help you but I also just recently encounter this issue. And this is how I fix it:

1. Close all tabs in vscode (try to revert any changes if possible).
2. Close vscode itself and open it again.
3. When you open vscode try to notice the initializing part at the bottom left, wait until it's done initializing.

[image]

4. Now, try to edit any file and save it.

Comment: Interesting I will keep an eye out for that. I manage to make the dialog not show up and thus be able to save my files my disabling both EsLint and Prettier Extensions. Obviously that is not ideal. I think it has to do more with the latest update on VS Code as there has many people recently experiencing similar issues

Comment: This is especially issue when do a screen share with Zoom. Usually works  if you open up VS Code (and wait for the Code initialization) first _prior to_ starting Zoom screen sharing.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem from docker related with the storage. I fixed this with the next commands.

WARNING!!!!: The docker images and containers well be deleted. You must be downloading images and build containers again.

```
 docker system df 
 docker image prune --force 
 docker container prune --force
```